# как удалить запись из БД с помощью Entity Framework Core

Tags: база-данных, entity-framework-core

как удалить запись из БД с помощью Entity Framework Core

Answer (score 0):

Документация [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/6.1.php) .

```
// удаление
int numberOfRowDeleted = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Companies WHERE Id={0}", id);
```

Не получается удалить конкретную запись? ошибки при удалении? Тогда нужно больше информации